# Select day of year from time dimension in SSAS as of today's date

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a time dimension which have dates and day of year(int).

```
select [day of year] 
from DimTime 
where date=getdate();
```

`Day of year` and `date` are columns in `DimTime` table. How I can write calculation in SSAS to get `day of year` as measure from `DimTime` dimension as per today's date?

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Please have a read here to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people answer your question, and review the following [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck.

Comment: TSQL Query: Select [day of year] from DimTime Where Date=getdate(). "day of year" and date are columns in DimTime table. How I can write calculation in SSAS to get [day of year] as measure from DimTime dimension?

Comment: Do you mean day number ? like 58th day of a year ?
Question is not very clear...

Comment: Yes, Like 58. Each date having a unique "day of year" . I want to get "day of year" value as per today's date.

Comment: Can someone help with query, please?

Answer (score 0):

What is your [Day of Year]? If possible, could you please inform me more detailed information (such as what is format of your [Day of year])? You could try to use format function to see whether it works or not.

You could refer to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1555eb27-f277-4f60-87ca-a2c2d6c12917/equivalent-function-in-mdx-for-monthx-as-in-sql?forum=sqlanalysisservices)  for more details.

Zoe